# Conjugaison d'avoir au futur antérieur

Tags: conjugaison

Est-ce que la phrase « Notez les sujets qui vous auront marque, ... » est correcte ?

Le sujet semble être « les sujets » donc « auront marque » semble valide mais Google retourne 0 résultats pour cette forme.

Comment: C'est correct, sans aucun doute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Le [futur antérieur](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/conjugaison/futur-anterieur-de-l-indicatif-47.php) se conjugue avec l’auxiliaire au futur suivi du participe passé;
- Marquer [utilise l'auxiliaire *avoir*](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/marquer.php);
- Le sujet du verbe *marquer* est *les sujets* donc troisième personne du pluriel;
- Le futur simple d'avoir à la troisième personne du pluriel est *auront*;
- Le participe passé de marquer est *marqué*;
- [Avec l'auxiliaire avoir, on accorde le participe passé avec le complément d'objet direct s'il y en a un et qu'il est placé avant le verbe](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accord_du_participe_pass%C3%A9_en_fran%C3%A7ais);
- *[Marquer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/marquer)* est ici intransitif (TLFi: Laisser une marque tangible, une trace, une impression durable). En absence de COD, il n'y a pas d'accord du participe passé.

La forme correcte est donc :

> Notez les sujets qui vous auront marqu**é**.

Comment: merci, aurais tu une reference au point de grammaire qui validerait la reponse ?